# Is $-1=\sqrt{1}$ true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find the solutions of
$$x=\sqrt{5+4x}.$$
I found that $x=5 \vee x=-1$. But is $-1=\sqrt{1}$ really true?

Comment: hum,how did you find that?I would like to be enlightened

Comment: $x=\sqrt{5+4x} \implies x^2 = 5+4x \implies x^2-4x-1=0 \implies (x-5)(x+1)=0$

Comment: Having found this you must always check (as you did). The right conclusion is that $x=5$. It appears to satisfy. This not the case for $x=-1$. This because $1=\sqrt{1}$ so $-1\ne\sqrt{1}$

Comment: @aflous At first I squared both sides. Subsequently I completed the square: $(x-2)^2=9$. But because squaring isn't an equivalent transformation I checked both solutions.

Comment: That's what I wanted you to say:squaring isn't an equivalent transformation, so you got your answer

Comment: The arrow $\implies$ only goes in one direction...

Comment: If this is just a math problem, then the $-1$ is extraneous.  If this is a real problem using math, then that $-1$ is important, and you need to double check your specifications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the only candidates possible for the solution are $x=-1$ and $x=5$. However, since in the process of getting these candidates, you had to square the equation, it may happen that you got some solutions that are not true, so you must inspect your candidates.

The first, $x=5$, put in the original equation, yields $5=\sqrt{25}$ which is true.

The second, however, yields $-1=\sqrt1$ which is not true, because $\sqrt{1} = 1$ (note that $\sqrt{a}$ is defined as the *positive number* such that its square is $a$).

Comment: Thanks! The information in your last sentence after "(" is exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: Happy to help. Just a quick fun fact: the direct consequence of my last sentence is the fact that $\sqrt{x^2}$ is actually not $x$, but $|x|$.

Answer (score 0):

But if u check this link:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=square+root+%281%29

it shows that principal root of $\sqrt(1)$ is 1. But -1 is also a real root of $sqrt(1)$